# Monitoring pandas.apply progress

Tags: python, pandas, apply, decorator, dask

I want to output the progress of the `apply()` method whenever an API call fails. Here is my code so far:

```py
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

c = 0

def translate_title(title):
    translated_titles = None

    while translated_titles == None:
        try:
            translated_titles = [part.text for part in translator.translate(title)]
            c += 1
        except:
            print(FILE_NAME, 'translation API limit reached. ' + str(c) + ' out of ' + LENGTH + ' rows translated.', flush=True)
            time.sleep(30)

    return translated_titles

ddf['translated_title'] = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: translate_title(row['title_clean']), axis=1), meta=(None, 'object'))
df = ddf.compute()
```

However, I am unable to change the value of `c` within the function. Is this a scoping issue? Or something that has to do with the way Dask works under the hood?

Comment: dask is a distributed processing library, making use of multiple threads, processes, or even servers. Sharing variables between dask tasks like you're trying to do with `c` is not a good idea. for one, integers are not mutable, so you cannot modify an integer variable in place with `+=` - this is actually a reassignment under the hood (in python - nothing to do with dask). Rather than trying to count successes, could you just use [`dask.diagnostics.ProgressBar`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/diagnostics-local.html)?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I just tried your solution. The progress bar starts at 97%. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: the progress bar on a blocking task like `compute()`. combines all tasks into a single progress indicator. you could also use `ddf = ddf.persist(); dask.distributed.progress(ddf)` to only track the most recent task, then compute the result to bring it into memory. For the most comprehensive task tracking though, use the dask dashboard.

Comment: whoa just realized you were doing an apply across all rows of a single column inside map_partitions. Why are you returning a list? shouldn't this just be a single value?